# Why cosine_similarity of pretrained fasttex model is high between two sentents are not relative at all?

Tags: word2vec, cosine-similarity, doc2vec, fasttext

I am wondering to know why pre-trained 'fasttext model' with wiki(Korean) seems not to work well! :(

model = fasttext.load_model("./fasttext/wiki.ko.bin")

model.cosine_similarity("테스트 테스트 이건 테스트 문장", "지금 아무 관계 없는 글 정말로 정말로")

(in english)
model.cosine_similarity("test test this is test sentence", "now not all relative docs really really ")

> 0.99....??
>   Those sentence is not at all relative as meaning. Therefore I think that cosine-similarity must be lower. However It was 0.997383...

Is it impossive to compare lone sentents with fasttext?
So Is it only way to use doc2vec?

Answer (score 0):

Which 'fasttext' code package are you using?

Are you sure its `cosine_similarity()` is designed to take such raw strings, and automatically tokenize/combine the words of each example to give sentence-level similarities? (Is that capability implied by its documentation or illustrative examples? Or perhaps does it expected pre-tokenized lists of words?)